# In how many ways can $15$ indistinguishable fish be placed into $5$ different ponds so that each pond contain at least one fish?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $15$ indistinguishable fish be placed into $5$ different ponds so that each pond contain at least one fish?

Answer (score 2):

We use a star ★ to represent a fish and a bar | as boundary between ponds. For the configuration where the first pond has 1 fish, the second pond has 2 fish, the third pond has 3 fish, the fourth pond has 4 fish, and the fifth pond has 5 fish, we represent it as:

> ★|★★|★★★|★★★★|★★★★★

We can see that each configuration of fish in ponds maps to exactly one configuration of stars and bars.

Observe that the bars cannot be consecutive (or else the pond would have no fish).

The bars also cannot be at the end or at the beginning.

Therefore, there are 14 slots between every two stars to place a bar, and we place 4 bars.

Therefore, the number of configurations is $\dbinom{14}4=1001$.

For reference: [Stars and bars (combinatorics), from Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).